# Htaccess Regex Not Accepting underscore

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am trying to write a regex which accepts a username with an underscore.

I can get it to work without a underscore, but when I add an underscore it gives a site error 500

Here is my regex I am using:

```
RewriteRule ^Activation/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ activationcodes.php?u=$1&a=$2 [L]
```

When I add the `_` it goes error 500 on the pages

```
RewriteRule ^Activation/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ activationcodes.php?u=$1&a=$2 [L]
```

Comment: My guess is that it sees `-` as a special character. Try escaping it (`\-`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the underscore *before* the dash:

```
RewriteRule ^Activation/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ activationcodes.php?u=$1&a=$2 [L]
```

Otherwise it thinks you mean "0 to 9 to _," which is wrong.

You could also escape it (which would also make it more readable):

```
RewriteRule ^Activation/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/?$ activationcodes.php?u=$1&a=$2 [L]
```